# Type 'std::string' could not be resolved.

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, native

I'd started porting some Java code in native c++ in Android. I have an issue with using strings in c++:

```
Type 'std::string' could not be resolved
```

There is my sample code

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <lexu_me_test_native.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_lexu_me_test_native_prepairToShowNative
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass javaThis, jstring str)
{
    jboolean blnIsCopy;
    jstring jstrOutput;
    char* strCOut;
    std::string ss;

    const char* strCIn = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(str , &blnIsCopy);
    // convert jstring to a char array
    // Do stuff with the char array and and store the result
    // in another char array strCOut
    (env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str , strCIn); // release jstring

    jstrOutput = (env)->NewStringUTF(strCOut); // convert char array to jstring
    return jstrOutput;
}
```

Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk file:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

MinGW installed and added to path. I tried using android-ndk-r8e and android-ndk-r8-crystax-1 nothing helped. In Cygwin Terminal errors:

```
Compile++ thumb  : native <= native.cpp
jni/native.cpp: In function '_jstring* Java_lexu_me_test_native_prepairToShowNative(JNIEnv*, jclass, jstring)':
jni/native.cpp:11:2: error: 'string' was not declared in this scope
jni/native.cpp:11:9: error: expected ';' before 'ss'
```

I'm using Win 7 64bit. Can anyone say how it could be solved?
Thanks.

**EDIT.**

In C/C++ General - Path and Symbols already set: C:\Android\android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include

Comment: `#include <string>`, `<string.h>` is a C library header.

Comment: using namespace std;
Try string instead of std::string

Comment: @Jite Don't suggest that. [using namespace std is bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @jrok #include <string> causes Unresolved inclusion: <string> and #include <cstring> too.

Comment: If you can't `#include <string>` your compiler setup is broken.

Comment: @DeadMG probably yes, but I download new version of SDK, Eclipse and NDK. Same result.

Comment: @Rapptz yes, I do feel the same, but bad practice or not, IF it's used, it should be used right :P

Comment: The right way to use `using namespace std;` is not at all.

Comment: @Jite "Type 'string' could not be resolved."

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers didn't work, then try these steps:

1. If you have `using namespace std;`, use `string` instead of `std::string`.
2. If `#include <string>` doesn't work and you're using Linux, try `#include <unistd.h>`. If you're using another OS, use `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: Hi, I'm changed  std::string  to  string, and added #include <string>. But Eclipse show errors  "Type 'string' could not be resolved" although in cygwin compile fine.

Comment: Then eclipse has a problem but i suggest you try `#include <cstdlib>` for windows or `#include <unistd.h>` for linux instead of `#include <string>`

Comment: #include <cstdlib> Eclipse accepted it, but warning didn't hide and compile in cygwing show error "'string' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: now i am sure that your computer doesn't have the string header or your ide(Eclipse) is broken.

Comment: i recommend visual studio if your a windows user because its really easy to work with and its free. go check it at [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads‎)

Comment: @shervin Visual Studio and Android's NDK aren't exactly best friends. It is possible to integrate the NDK into Visual Studio. However, [vs-android](http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/) is flaky, at best. And [VisualGDB](http://visualgdb.com/) is a commercial product that requires a commercial Visual Studio Edition.

Comment: *"But Eclipse show errors "Type 'string' could not be resolved" although in cygwin compile fine..."* - Also see [Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23155676). Eclipse and the plugin broke during a NDK update and it was never fixed. It was never fixed presumably because of Android Studio, which does not support JNI...

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` files. Ensure you select an STL library and include int the `Application.mk` file:

```
Application.mk: APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

(gnustl_static) can be replaced with the STL version you want, and STLPort is still an option

See http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Wow was this a long time ago. I'll update the answer. However, see http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html

Comment: Link is dead but I don't understand the criticism. If the system isn't setup properly, that would cause such an error.